# GluonVM, source and JDK compatibility

Tags: java-9, gluon

So GluonVM states that it supports Java 9 modules, and the Java 9 JavaFX API (http://docs.gluonhq.com/gluonvm/), but the sample project specifies source compatibility 1.8.

I'm confused how to setup my project in Eclipse; with source compatibilty at 8 the Gradle plugin of Eclipse will automatically select a Java 8 compatible JDK. Should I configure JDK 9.0.4 as the Java8-SDK? And then use the JavaFX 9 API (future proof code)? And do I need to specify a module-info.java? I would like to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you know, Gluon's jfxmobile plugin has two flavors for now: 1.3.15+ and 2.0.30+.

The 1.3.15+ version works on Desktop, Android and iOS with JDK 8.

The 2.0.30+ version uses Gluon VM and it works:

- On Desktop under JDK 8, 9 or 10.
- On Android under JDK 8, 9 or 10, but everything has to be back ported to 8. So you need Java 8 compatibility in all your dependencies. This explains why module-info is not supported.
- On iOS under JDK 9 or 10. You could remove the 8 compatibility if you deploy only to iOS.

As you can see, the bottleneck here is Android, as it doesn't allow Java 9+ yet.

However, there is work in [progress](https://twitter.com/johanvos/status/1047804607320260608) to get JavaFX 11+ running on Android as well, so that will bring *all* the platforms to the same level:

- Desktop runs JavaFX 11+
- Embedded runs JavaFX 11+ (see [this](https://gluonhq.com/javafx-11-early-access-on-embedded/))
- Gluon VM on iOS will support JavaFX 11+
- Android will support JavaFX 11+.

Comment: So the answer is: use Java 8. Ok.